# How to update the form dependencies for laravel 5.3 or 5.4 project which is already installed

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I have followed these steps,

First, added your new provider to the providers array of config/app.php:

```
 'providers' => [
    // ...
            LaravelCollective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

Next, add two class aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php:

```
 'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => LaravelCollective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => LaravelCollective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

finally 
 on terminal,

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

I have tried running composer update, after that my page keeps on showing 500 error. That is no page is getting loaded.

Comment: check httpd error log or run built-in server with your project (artisan serve) and see what's show up)

Comment: Laravel development server started on http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Comment: artisan serve showed me the above one @MarcinOrlowski

Comment: ok, but when you do http request to your site, isn't it showing anything? is it working or what?

Comment: No nothing was showed except this.                                                                         The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500 @MarcinOrlowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assumed you updated your

```
laravel/framework dependency to 5.4.*
```

in your

```
composer.json file.
```

In addition, you should update your

```
phpunit/phpunit dependency to ~5.7
```

you should also make

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

and

```
php artisan config:cache
```